# Fail code coverage if no tests exist for code

Tags: node.js, istanbul

I have a simple Node JS application and am using Istanbul with Mocha to generate code coverage reports.  This is working fine.

If I write a new function, but do not create any tests for it (or even create a test file) is it possible to check for this?

My ultimate goal is for any code which has no tests at all to be picked up by our continuous integration process and for it to fail that build.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could achieve this is by using code coverage.

```
"check-coverage": "istanbul check-coverage --root coverage --lines 98 --functions 98 --statements 98 --branches 98"
```

Just add this in your `package.json` file, change the threshold if needed. If code is written but no test then the coverage will go down.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your answer.  I am already using that command in my package.json but it doesn't seem to be picking up the file I have with no tests.  Also before I can run that command it seems I have to run the `cover` command first to generate a `coverage.json` file ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to solve the problem but by running the `cover` command first and adding the parameter `--include-all-sources` this then reported on any code without a test file and added them to the `coverage.json` file it generated.

Then running the `check-coverage` would fail which is what I'm after.  In my CI process I would run `cover` first, then `check-coverage`

Personally I find the documentation on Istanbul a little bit confusing/un-clear which is why I didn't see this at first!